# Complex filtration logic in Groovy findAll closure

Tags: groovy, closures

Groovy here. I need to filter a `Set` of POGOs using somewhat complex logic, and I'm struggling with understanding the proper use of the `findAll` closure.

```
@Canonical
class Widget {
    String name
    Boolean fizzbuzz
}

...

Set<Widget> filter(Integer isHidden, Set<Widget> inputWidgets) {
    inputWidgets.findAll { widget ->
        Foobar foobar = FoobarHelper.getFoobarByWidget(widget)

        // Logic:
        // If isHidden is 0 and no foorbar exists for the given widget,
        // then we want to add this widget to the collection being
        // returned...
        if(isHidden.intValue() == 0 && !foobar) {
            // Add this widget to collection being returned
            ???
        }

        // ...but if isHidden is 1 and a foobar does exist for the given
        // widget, then we want to add this widget to the collection as
        // well.
        else if(isHidden.intValue() == 1 && foobar) {
            // Add this widget to collection being returned
            ???
        }
    }
}
```

So again the filtration logic is:

- If `isHidden == 0` and `FoobarHelper.getFoobarByWidget(...)` returns `null`, then add the current `widget` to the collection being returned; and
- If `isHidden == 1` and `FoobarHelper.getFoobarByWidget(...)` returns non-`null`, then add the current `widget` to the collection being returned

I *think* my logic implementation is correct, I'm just struggling with how to add the current `widget` to the return collection (where the ??? are). **Any ideas?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it should just be:

```
@Canonical
class Widget {
    String name
    Boolean fizzbuzz
}

...

Set<Widget> filter(Integer isHidden, Set<Widget> inputWidgets) {
    inputWidgets.findAll { widget ->
        Foobar foobar = FoobarHelper.getFoobarByWidget(widget)
        (isHidden.intValue() == 0 && !foobar) || (isHidden.intValue() == 1 && foobar)
    }
}
```

In this single line:

```
(isHidden.intValue() == 0 && !foobar) || (isHidden.intValue() == 1 && foobar)
```

you are checking both conditions. All elements that satisfy either of them will be added to the returned collection.